# How to remove duplicated rows in Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql-9.1

I have a table named "phone_number_list" which has id, phone_number, org_id, created_at. I am trying to run a query that will remove the duplicated phone_number for each org_id in the table. Can anyone help me with this? I know how to do this with MySQL, but first time use Postgresql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
delete from your_table where id in 
   (select max(id) from your_table
     group by org_id, phone_number
     having count(1) > 1);
```

[Here's a working sample at DB-Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gRxKScCJnJ4UwgLXRFqauA/0#&togetherjs=sA3UepOhHE). It's working properly.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using Window Functions:

```
DELETE FROM phone_number_list 
 WHERE id IN 
    (SELECT id FROM 
       ( SELECT id, ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
         (partition BY phone_number, org_id ORDER BY id ASC) AS rnum
         FROM phone_number_list
       ) AS t WHERE t.rnum > 1);
```